# dynamic keyword affects return type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-core

I'm not entirley sure why the following code compiles

```
namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    public class Person
    {

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic expand = new ExpandoObject();
            List<Person> people = GetPerson(expand);

        }

        public static Person GetPerson(int item)
        {
            return new Person();
        }

    }
}
```

Why does the `dynamic` keyword impact the return type. It's like the compiler give's up on type checking as soon as `dynamic` is introduced. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes. Almost *anything* you do that involves a dynamic value ends up with a compile-time type of `dynamic`. Note that binding is performed dynamically, so even though in this specific case you've only got one `GetPerson` method, in the more *general* case of method invocation, overloads could be present at execution time that aren't present at compile-time, with different return types.

There are a few operations which *don't* end up with a dynamic type:

- Casting (e.g. `(string) dynamicValue`)
- The `is` operator (e.g. `dynamicValue is string`)
- The `as` operator (e.g. `dynamicValue as string`
- Constructor calls (e.g. `new Foo(dynamicValue)`)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up looking deeper at the IL and then understood what was going on but thank you got the explanation, much appreciated